# MySQL `SELECT` query does not return the newest data

Tags: mysql, python

There are 3 servers: `nginx` server, `fastapi` server and `mysql` server.

`nginx` server: web page on `/admin/`

`fastapi` server: api page on `/api/select/`

`mysql` server: stores the data (`mysql` version `8.3.0`)

`/admin/` page will post to `/api/select/` when it is loaded, and `/api/select/` will return all the records in table `test`.

The wierd thing is: when I insert a new record into table `test` using phpmyadmin, it will never be updated to `/admin/`. To be more strange, if I `$.post` manually in the web page, the post result will be alternately updated and unupdated.

[The result of the manual posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnk8L.png)

PS: The path `/api/admin/select/company/` is aliases as `/api/select/` in the question.

If I reboot the server, the post data will be updated.

I have completely no idea why this should happen.

Comment: My total guess would be some sort of caching is occurring in your API setup

Comment: I can exclude the possibility of the cache of browser, since I add some debug code in the FastAPI server, and it does reads from the database and get the wrong result.

Comment: @BarryCarter I use `aiomysql` package in my `FastAPI` server. I heard that it would not store any caches.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved by setting `autocommit=True` in `aiomysql` connection. However, I can't see why `select` query needs `commit`.

Comment: Show us the _generated SQL_ so we can see the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: There is a whole lot of machinery between the input and the output. You have provided no details of this. You have provided no evidence to support some what appears to be enormous assumptions about what is happening in that machinery. And its off-topic here - programming questions should be posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: 'No commit' when you know it should be committed = your question will be repeated in time.  And repeated again in a few hours, days, weeks.

Comment: @symcbean I posted the problem on stackoverflow, and was closed for the reason it's off-topic.